# entering array fetched from a file into database table

Tags: java, mysql, arrays

My aim was to fetch a file and split the values from the file and enter the values into the database table.

I have created an example table `empp` with two columns `empname, empid`. I connected to the database and tried to insert query from 'eclipse'.

Now I have the file `fr.txt`. When I read the file, split the values and store it in an array, I am unable to use the array indexes in the insert query.

here is my code:

```
try{
    FileReader fr=new FileReader("C:\\Users\\Priyanka Sethi\\Desktop\\fr.txt");
    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(fr);
    String str;
    str=br.readLine();
    while((str=br.readLine())!=null){
        System.out.println(str+"\n");       
        String [] array = str.split("\\,");
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(array[i]); 
        }
        String a=array[0];
        Integer b=Integer.parseInt(a);
        String c=array[1];
        Connection con=getConnection();
        PreparedStatement posted=con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO empp(empid,empname)VALUES(b,'c')");
        posted.executeUpdate();
    }
} catch(Exception e){
    System.out.println(e);
} finally {
    System.out.println("insertion completed");
}
```

Comment: "i am unable to use the array indexes" What do you mean? Are you getting an exception that you can add to your question?

Comment: Can you post sample data from the File?

Comment: Please also read some resources about sanitizing SQL data. That will put you ahead of the competition.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in how you're attempting to place values into your `PreparedStatement`.

You have:

```
PreparedStatement posted=con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO empp(empid,empname)VALUES(b,'c')");
```

...which isn't actually using the variables `b` and `c` which you created in the lines above. Instead, try using The [PreparedStatement.setString(int, String)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setString(int,%20java.lang.String)) and [PreparedStatement.setInt(int, int)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setInt(int,%20int)) methods.

For a full example take a look at this:
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javaexamples/jdbc_prepared_statement.htm

In your case - without actually running your code to test - I would change that line to look like this:

```
PreparedStatement posted=con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO empp(empid,empname)VALUES(?,?)");
posted.setInt(1, b.intValue());
posted.setString(2, c);
```

---

## DISCLAIMER

**ALWAYS, ALWAYS, *ALWAYS* validate, sanitize, etc. *ANY* input from a user. NEVER directly use values in any query which have been provided from outside your program, and NEVER make any assumptions about what a user will enter. Doing so opens you up to a wide array of vulnerabilities. Using good practices is important from the start!**

Comment: Although what I'm about to suggest doesn't answer the direct question, I highly suggest you add a disclaimer about inserting values read in from outside the program. That would make this answer even better. This is one of the *big* vulnerabilities that new programmers introduce into systems that get compromised later on.

Comment: @Aaron Ah yes, definitely an important note to add - thanks for the reminder to do so!

Comment: I wasn't expecting it on such a loud bulletin board, but that still gets the +1.

Comment: @Aaron Important notes need to be noticed :)